# Install a package from the current release

Tags: debian, apt

As far as I remember for one reason or another this Debian Jessie server had incorrect `sources.list` file for a while. Meaning, it was pointing to the newer release. But I don't think many packages were installed during that period. One of such packages is `debconf`:

```
# apt list --installed debconf
debconf/now 1.5.65 all [installed,local]
```

The proper version (`1.5.56+deb8u1`) exists in the repository:

```
# apt-cache policy debconf
debconf:
  Installed: 1.5.65
  Candidate: 1.5.65
  Version table:
 *** 1.5.65 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.5.56+deb8u1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages

# apt-cache showpkg debconf | sed -E '/^Reverse Depends:/ q' | egrep '^(Versions:|1.5)'
Versions: 
1.5.65 (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
1.5.56+deb8u1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-amd64_Packages)

# apt-cache show debconf | egrep '^(Package|Version|Status):'
Package: debconf
Status: install ok installed
Version: 1.5.65
Package: debconf
Version: 1.5.56+deb8u1

# curl -sS http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | zcat | sed -nE '/^Package: debconf$/,/^Package:/p' | egrep '^(Package|Version|Filename):' | head -n -1
Package: debconf
Version: 1.5.56+deb8u1
Filename: pool/main/d/debconf/debconf_1.5.56+deb8u1_all.deb

# curl -sS --head -o /dev/null --fail http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debconf/debconf_1.5.56+deb8u1_all.deb2; echo $?
0
```

But it doesn't get installed:

```
# apt-get install --reinstall debconf
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Reinstallation of debconf is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 79 not upgraded.
```

Is there a way to make it work without upgrading to Stretch or higher?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `apt-get install debconf=1.5.56+deb8u1`, but if multiple packages were upgraded beyond jessie, you might have a hard time restoring a pure jessie system, because downgrading is not supported in general. You can force a mass-downgrade by setting the priority of the jessie repo to more than 1000, though.

Comment: Actually, the magnitude of the disaster was more than I expected. 376 packages newer than those of the Jessie release. Some packages are newer than those coming with Stretch (`debconf`, `perl`). I asked on `#debian` channel, and they recommended to upgrade Jessie -> Stretch, then Stretch -> Buster. Possibly Jessie -> Stretch, then careful downgrade of the newer stuff to Stretch. Or if I'm going to lose less than, say, a day of work, then reinstall the OS. More info: https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/297d69ff443e7630407cb18f624dcb31 https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/8dc7bd6b8aab5f07ca9cf6aa82976a18